# Estimating LOE for TFS Customization - add a WIT to a project

Tags: tfs

For a full-time TFS admin professional, about how many hours would go into "customizing" an existing scrum template project to add an additional work item type?

Comment: My ask was that a new work item type be added to our project.  The TFS admin said 3+ month lead time.
Seems to me if that's the case then this product isn't designed all that well, or the TFS admins......

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add a new WIT is to copy an existing WIT and then modify the definition file. You have two options to achieve it:

1. You can install [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1), this tool provides an add-in to the Team menu and a new section on the Work Items page in Team Explorer. Use this tool to create new work items with default values, or to easily apply values to existing work items.
2. You can export the a WIT definition files, and edit it, then import it. Useful links:

   - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-modify-wit#add-wit
   - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404855.aspx

Regarding how many hours it will cost, it depends on your detailed requirement and whether you are familiar with TFS Power Tools and WIT definition files. If you just want to create a new WIT based an existing WIT, and just add some field, it will only need several minutes with TFS Power Tool.